# For positive measures $\nu_j$, is $\left(\sum_1^\infty \nu_j\right)(E) \le \sum_1^\infty \nu_j(E)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

I am trying to solve the following homework problem, where the notation $\nu \perp \mu$ means that $\nu$ and $\mu$ are mutually singular:

> Suppose $\{\nu_j\}$ is a sequence of positive measures. If $\nu_j \perp \mu$ for all $j$, then $\sum_1^\infty \nu_j \perp \mu$; and if $\nu_j \ll \mu$ for all $j$, then $\sum_1^\infty \nu_j \ll \mu$.

I have seen a similar question asked for *finite* measures, but here we only restrict $\nu_j \ge 0$ for all $j$.

My proof relies on two key points:

- $\sum_1^\infty \nu_j$ is a measure;
- $\left(\sum_1^\infty \nu_j\right)(E) \le \sum_1^\infty \nu_j(E)$ for all appropriate $E$.

However, I am having difficulty justifying the second point. All of the references I would use hinge on $\nu_j$ being finite. Some guidance is appreciated.

Comment: I presume the definition of $\sum_j v_j$ is $(\sum_j v_j)(E)= \sum_j (v_j(E))$?

Comment: If $E$ is a set, what is your definition of $(\sum_1^\infty \nu_j)(E)$?

Comment: @copper.hat Since $\sum_1^\infty \nu_j$ is a measure, $\left(\sum_1^\infty \nu_j\right)(E)$ denotes that measure of the set $E$. If it is simpler, let $\lambda = \sum_1^\infty\nu_j$; I need to explore $\lambda(E)$.

Comment: In other words, is $\left(\sum_1^\infty \nu_j\right)(E) = \sum_1^\infty \nu_j(E)$ *by definition* and I am just being daft? Unfortunately, I cannot find this notation defined in my textbook.

Comment: I am asking how you define $(\sum_j v_j)$. If it is defined as the sum of measures of a set then it is indeed a measure.

Comment: I would imagine that it is defined that way. Since it is positive, it is easy to check that it is a measure.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805857/countable-sum-of-measures-is-a-measure. The definition of $(\sum_n \nu_n)(E)=\sum_n \nu_n(E)$

Comment: @copper.hat I guess it must be. I will have to explore where finiteness is used in other proofs, as my approach seems to be identical but does not require that property.

Comment: You don't need finiteness. I mean, it may a pretty useless measure if it is $\infty$ everywhere (except for $\emptyset$) but it is still a measure.

Comment: @copper.hat In such a case, I wish I had back my restless 45 minutes of overthinking this problem last night.

Comment: Mathematics is a dangerous and merciless siren. I have done far worse for far longer.

Comment: @copper.hat That was beautiful. It made me laugh. And cry. And then cry some more.

Comment: @Moya: I wish I was joking ;-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide an answer to the question: the sum of positive measures is a measure (not difficult to show), and by convention we write $\left(\sum \nu_j \right)(E) = \sum \nu_j (E)$, where the sum can be finite or infinite, as each term is positive.